# Running Cron on a specifc server in AWS

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, cron

I am developing a project in spring. In this project I have written a cron job as well. I am going to deploy this on 4 AWS servers, but I want my cron job to run on only a single server (let's name that as admin server). 
So here my question is how can I identify admin server uniquely. I was thinking to use the IP as identification but as far as I know IP is not static for AWS servers. is there any other way for identification so that I can put that check in my cron job code so that it will run only on admin server?

Answer (score 0):

You can always start the admin instance with [some user data as metadata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html) or [add a tag](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Using_Tags.html) to your instance.

The metadata solution might be easier to integrate as you can just issue an unauthenticated HTTP request from within the instance to read the value. If that is a security concern for you, then you can go with the tag and use the API to retrieve the tag value.